# How do I correctly add html attributes to Django form widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to use Parsley.js for validation in my Django project.  I am currently at the step where I am trying to add the necessary Parsley attributes to the form fields.  Hopefully this is correct, but I was told I need pass the attributes to the widget in this existing form field.

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,
                                                                   maxlength=75)),label=_("Email"))
```

My question is how do I a correctly pass the attributes to the form widget so that I can validate this form field with parsley.js?  I took a stab at it below, but I know it's incorrect.

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,
                                                                   maxlength=75, data-required="true", data-trigger="keyup")), label=_("Email"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `__init__` function in your form class may be the best option...

```
class YourClass(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['yourfield'].widget.attrs.update({'yourattribute': 'yourattributevalue'})
```

Comment: So there's no way to just pass the attributes into the example I included?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in the attributes directly to field declaration like so:

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-trigger':'keyup', 'data-required' : 'true'}), maxlength=75, label=_("Email"))
```

See django form widget attrs documentation for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Comment: I suspect this is close to the answer I'm looking for but this gives a syntax error.